# I need to use an integer as an object

Tags: c++

I need to have an int type ( or similar ) and attach to it methods.

So I am using:

```
struct INT{
    int i;
    operator int(){return i;};
    int operator=(int v){return i=v;}
    void p(){std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

INT X;
int i=8;

X=5;

int j=X+i;
X=j;

(*reinterpret_cast<INT*>(&i)).p();

reinterpret_cast<INT>(i).p();

X.p();

}
```

While the second form of reinterpret_cast should work, it doesn't with no apparent semantic explanation.
Do you know why ?

Comment: `While the second form of reinterpret_cast should work`: Why is that ?

Comment: Don't use `reinterpret_cast` unless you actually know what you are doing. Your first one invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe, but it does what I want to do ! So that seems the only way, but is shouldn't.

Comment: Why do you use reinterpret_cast anyway? Use static_cast, I think that is what you want to do here.

Comment: Static cast fails to compile in both forms.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis, "Maybe, but it does what I want to do ! So that seems the only way, but is shouldn't." - the fact you get a result, is a simple coincidence, not the compiler doing what you want. This is undefined behavior (you are effectively lying to the compiler, saying the address represents an INT, when it doesn't). This code can be broken by: OS load level, OS, compiler options, running multithreaded or not (and probably, current planetary alignment). This code _doesn't_ do what you want it to.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` from `INT&` to `int&` is safe, because the `int` is the very first member of a standard layout class. It is however silly: there is no advantage over just producing the `int` value. Going the other way is generally Undefined Behavior, since the class type object may have stricter alignment. re the "should work" about one of the silly casts, that particular cast should not even compile. does it?

Answer (score 5):

`reinterpret_cast` is primarily used to perform [*dangerous* pointer conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). Use it when you actually know what you are doing, not just to shut up the compiler.

Casting an `int *` pointing to an `int` to an `INT *` and attempting to call a member function of `INT` with that causes *undefined behavior*. A conforming compiler is free to generate code that chomps up your hard drive instead.

The correct way to do this is to use `static_cast` with a converting constructor in `INT`:

```
struct INT{
    INT(int i_ = 0) : i(i_) { }  // defines implicit conversion
    int i;
    operator int(){return i;};
    int operator=(int v){return i=v;}
    void p(){std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    INT X;
    int i=8;

    static_cast<INT>(i).p();

    X.p();    
}
```

Comment: I don't whant to construct another object equal to the same I alrady have. I just want to access to use the same 32bits that constitute the int, as INT or int

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: In that case, perhaps `INT` should hold a reference to int (that is -- `int&`) rather than an `int`.

Comment: Essentially I need a union holding int and INT and using whatever I want, but without the burden of the field names.

Comment: In point of fact, the claim that casting an `int *` to an `INT *` results in undefined behaviour is *incorrect*.  The C and C++ standards guarantee pointer equivalence for the first element of a (POD) `struct`; that is, if a `struct S` starts with `T foo;`, then a pointer `S *` can be safely cast to a pointer `T *`.  It follows that, if the POD `struct` contains only that single member, it is also safe to cast back the other way (and it *may* be safe to do so in other circumstances, provided you know that it’s really a pointer to an `S`, not just a `T`).

Comment: @alastair: re "It follows that, if the POD struct contains only that single member, it is also safe to cast back the other way", nope, that depends on the alignement of the types. note by the way that there's a little self-contradiction in the standard here, about the alignment requirements, but not so much that it's worth reporting as a defect, i think. i stopped reporting defects when the last one only made it half-way; i think they're very very busy.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf IIRC the alignment of a POD `struct` is defined to be the same as the alignment of its first member — unless I'm remembering incorrectly, anyway.

Comment: @alastair: you are indeed remembering incorrectly. if first member is `char`, and later on there is `double`, aligning as `char` would foul up alignment of the `double`. which depending on OS and machine might crash, or just be extremely inefficient.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ah, you’re quite right (my copies of the standards are currently all boxed up where I can't get them, so I have to rely on memory, which is not always accurate).  However, in this particular instance there are no such alignment concerns.

Comment: @alastair I think you are right that casting from `int *` to `INT *` and accessing the stored value doesn't violate strict aliasing, which is what I had in mind when I wrote that sentence. However, calling a `INT` member function with the resulting pointer is clearly UB.

Answer (score 3):

C++ unlike Java has free functions:

```
void p(int i)
{
  std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

We therefore don't need to "attach" methods to integers.

Comment: If we don't need to attach methods to integers, why should we need to attach methods to structures ? By the same reasoning, don't use any methods.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: Well, to access private members for instance - which `int` doesn't have. But the direction of your idea is indeed correct: don't use methods if free functions work.

Comment: This isn't an answer the OP's question (why his `reinterpret_cast` doesn’t work).

Comment: @alastair: Read up on XY problems. I'm answering the underlying question, not the stated question. As the OP's comment shows, he incorrectly assumed methods were preferred over free functions.

Answer (score 2):

The first cast works because of *pointer equivalence*; that is, the C and C++ standards explicitly state that, for POD `struct`s, it’s safe to cast a pointer to the structure to a pointer to the type of its first element.  That is, given

```
struct S {
  T foo;
  ...
};

S s;
S *pS = &s;
```

it's quite legal to access `foo` through a pointer obtained thusly:

```
T *pFoo = (T *)pS;
```

It also follows from this, because of the nature of POD types, that:

1. If the structure has only a single element, then it's *always* safe to cast back the other way.
2. If the structure has more than one element, it's safe to cast back the other way if you *know* that the pointer really points to the structure and not just to something with the type of its first element.

So, the first cast *is legal*, is *not* undefined, and should always work.

The *second* cast, on the other hand, is problematic.  The reason for this is that compilers are not guaranteed to treat a single-element struct in the same way as its first element *in any sense other than pointer equivalence*.  This makes sense because the code you would expect a compiler to generate for a `struct` type is quite different to that you’d expect for e.g. an `int`; the `int` is likely to be assigned a register, but `struct` types generally aren't held in registers and instead are stored on the stack and referred to by address.  As a result, `reinterpret_cast` simply isn't defined for the case that you want.  There’s a [good summary of the rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) on the [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com).

Comment: i think you're reading the first cast the wrong way. it casts to INT*.

Comment: No, I'm definitely reading it right.  *Pointer equivalence* says that `int *` and `INT *` are equivalent in this case, so casting between them (in either direction) should be safe.

Comment: re "asting between them (in either direction) should be safe", not when the `int` isn't originally a first member of an `INT` struct. the `INT` can then have more strict alignment requirement than the address of the `int`. as a simple example consider a struct with a `char` first member, followed by a `double`. the compiler can then freely assume proper alignment and e.g. translate check of first member to loading a 32-bit word and checking that. so a `char` pointer pointing to odd address, can't usually be casted to point to such struct.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But in this particular case, `int` *is* the first member. That’s the entire point — that’s why the pointer equivalence rule applies.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm obviously missing your point here.  There is no alignment concern with a single member struct containing an "int".  The cast is well-defined.

Comment: @alastair: The rule (I believe) you are trying to invoke is `[class.mem]/20` `A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.`. This rule does not apply in this case, because the `int*` does not point to the first member of an `INT` object. (`&X.i` would be a suitable `int*`).

Comment: Alf's alignment comment was just giving an example of a possible failure mode, but strictly, dereference after the cast is undefined behaviour, so even if the alignment were fine, there could be any number of other problems introduced by the compiler or runtime system.

Comment: @Mankarse I see your argument, but I think it's a technicality.  The layout for `struct { int a; } s;` and `int t;` is identical (and that *is* mandated by the standard).  So while it may *technically* not point to the first member of an `INT` object, in practice it points to memory that has the exact same layout, alignment and content, as guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @alastair: I'd be interested in the standard's wording that guarantees "the exact same ... alignment". For example, that would *guarantee* that `struct Ch { char value; };` is 1 byte with no alignment. AFAIK it is so (for that example) with all extant compilers, but the standard's wording would be nice.